# getting stuck with C pointer Structure

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, structure, zigbee

I am working on Embedded C . I am stuck with pointer structure ....

Structures are given below ..

```
/*structure 1*/
ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTableType *psAplApsmeAibBindingTable;

/*structure 2*/
typedef struct
{
    ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTableCache* psAplApsmeBindingTableCache;
    ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTable* psAplApsmeBindingTable;
}ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTableType;

/*structure3*/
typedef struct
{
   uint64  u64SourceAddress;
   ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTableEntry* pvAplApsmeBindingTableEntryForSpSrcAddr;
   uint32 u32SizeOfBindingTable;
}ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTable;

/*structure 4*/
typedef struct
{
   ZPS_tuAddress  uDstAddress;
   uint16  u16ClusterId;
   uint8   u8DstAddrMode;
   uint8   u8SourceEndpoint;
   uint8   u8DestinationEndPoint;
} ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTableEntry;
```

I have declared `ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTableType *p;` but i want to access `ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTableEntry` structure values... How could i do that??

Can anyone tell me the difference between

```
ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTable* psAplApsmeBindingTable
```

and

```
ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTable *psAplApsmeBindingTable;
```

Thanks ....

Comment: I'm stuck on your naming conventions!  Wow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `p->psAplApsmeBindingTable->pvAplApsmeBindingTableEntryForSpSrcAddr->someField`
2. No difference.

PS. That code is really, really ugly.

Comment: and I think ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTable* psAplApsmeBindingTable is a array of structure ...if i use psAplApsmeBindingTable[0].someval or psAplApsmeBindingTable->someptr its showing a illegal address alignment

Answer (score 2):

```
ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTable* psAplApsmeBindingTable;
```

and

```
ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTable *psAplApsmeBindingTable;
```

and

```
ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTable * psAplApsmeBindingTable;
```

Are **the same**. The location of the `*` does not change anything.

---

To access values of a struct pointed to by a pointer (like your pointer `p`), you can use an arrow `->`

```
p->psAplApsmeBindingTable->pvAplApsmeBindingTableEntryForSpSrcAddr->u16ClusterId
```

Comment: but sir it's show me error .. ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTable* psAplApsmeBindingTable its a array of structure pointed by psAplApsmeBindingTable.. if i use  
p->psAplApsmeBindingTable[0].u64SourceAddress again its show error.. please suggest a way to solve it..

Comment: have you tried `p->psAplApsmeBindingTable[0]->u64SourceAddress ` ?

Answer (score 1):

> I have declared ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTableType *p; but i want to access ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTableEntry structure values... How could i do that??

Well you can't.  In your code a `ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTableType` does not contain any members of the type `ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTableEntry` or `ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTableEntry*`.

> Can anyone tell me the difference between ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTable* psAplApsmeBindingTable and ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTable *psAplApsmeBindingTable;

There is no difference; they are the same thing... literally the same text copied twice.  I don't really understand your question.  If you could elaborate a bit I may be able to help further.

Comment: suppose when a array of structure is pointed by a structure pointer
ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTable* psAplApsmeBindingTable its a structure pointer .... i want to access those values in that location ...

Answer (score 0):

You'd get to the `ZPS_tsAplApsmeBindingTableEntry` members as follows:

```
p->psAplApsmeBindingTable->pvAplApsmeBindingTableEntryForSpSrcAddr->uDstAddress
p->psAplApsmeBindingTable->pvAplApsmeBindingTableEntryForSpSrcAddr->u16ClusterId
p->psAplApsmeBindingTable->pvAplApsmeBindingTableEntryForSpSrcAddr->u8DstAddrMode
```

etc.  You would use the `->` for all selections because `p`, `psAplApsmeBindingTable`, and `pvAplApsmeBindingTableEntryForSpSrcAddr` are all pointers to struct types.  If any of them had *not* been pointer types, you would have used the `.` operator to do the component selection for that type.  For example:

```
struct a {int x; int y};
struct b {struct a *p; struct a v};
struct b foo, *bar = &foo;
...
foo.p->x = ...;  // foo is not a pointer type, p is a pointer type
bar->v.y = ...;  // bar is a pointer type, v is not a pointer type
```

The expression `x->y` is shorthand for `(*x).y`; IOW, you dereference `x` and then select `y`.

There is no difference between the declarations

```
T *p;
```

and

```
T* p;
```

Both are interpreted as `T (*p);` - the `*` is always part of the *declarator*, not the type specifier.  If you wrote

```
T* a, b;
```

only `a` would be declared as a pointer to `T`; `b` would be declared as a plain `T`.